# Combining Multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, class

I have the following two functions that do the same thing, any way I can combine these two functions into a single function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav li").removeClass("current_page_item");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("current_page_item");
    });
    $("#overlay li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#overlay li").removeClass("current_page_item");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("current_page_item");
    });
});
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: why not just add the same class to both the ul then you can target that class - after all that's what class names are meant, targeting like elements (or just add the class to the li and target them directly - will make your jquery selector a lot more efficient)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a pair of selectors combined with a comma. The matching elements for both selectors will be returned:

```
$("#nav li, #overlay li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#nav, #overlay').find('li').removeClass("current_page_item");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("current_page_item");
});
```

To deselect the other elements when this is clicked, find the ancestor matching the container ID (`nav` or `overlay`), and remove the `current_page_item` class from the descendant `li` elements.

Comment: `$(this)` to `$(this).closest('#nav, #overlay').find('li')` should allow you to keep the logic and remedy the not changing siblings.  Edit: and the closest on the last command is pointless as the `this` *is* an li.

Comment: This works great! I tried the comma separating the selectors on the function, but missed it on the this.closest...thanks!